# Parse Nested Level Json In javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

Sample Input:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "p1",
    "top": 130,
    "left": 298,
    "Key": "test1",
    "Next": "special"
  },
  {
    "id": "p2",
    "Key": "special",
    "specialkey": [
      {"key": "1", "value": "p3"},
      {"key": "0", "value": "p4"},
      {"key": "2", "value": "p5"}
    ],
    "Next": "",
    "RepeatText": "p8",
    "RepeatTextNew": "p9",
  },
  {
    "id": "p3",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test3",
    "Text": "hi"
  },
  {
    "id": "p4",
    "Key": "special",
    "specialkey": [
      {"key": "1", "value": "p6"},
      {"key": "0", "value": "p7"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "p5",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test5",
    "Text": "hi"
  },
  {
    "id": "p6",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test6",
    "Text": "hi"
  },
  {
    "id": "p7",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test7",
    "Text": "hi"
  },
  {
    "id": "p8",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test8",
    "Text": "hi"
  },
 {
    "id": "p9",
    "user": "aa",
    "Key": "test9",
    "Text": "hi"
  }
]
```

Sample Output:

```json
{
  "test1": {
    "id": "p1",
    "top": 130,
    "left": 298,
    "Key": "test1",
    "Next": {
      "special": {
        "id": "p2",
        "Key": "special",
        "Next": "",
        "RepeatText": {
          "p8": {
            "id": "p8",
            "user": "aa",
            "Key": "test8",
            "Text": "hi"
          }
        },
        "RepeatTextNew": {
          "p9": {
            "id": "p9",
            "user": "aa",
            "Key": "test9",
            "Text": "hi"
          }
        },
        "specialkey": [
          {
            "key": "1",
            "value": {
              "id": "p3",
              "user": "aa",
              "Key": "test3",
              "Text": "hi"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "0",
            "value": {
              "id": "p4",
              "Key": "special",
              "specialkey": [
                {
                  "key": "1",
                  "value": {
                    "id": "p6",
                    "user": "aa",
                    "Key": "test6",
                    "Text": "hi"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key": "0",
                  "value": {
                    "id": "p7",
                    "user": "aa",
                    "Key": "test7",
                    "Text": "hi"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "2",
            "value": {
              "id": "p5",
              "user": "aa",
              "Key": "test5",
              "Text": "hi"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the key is equal to `special` it can have a nested structure and for either we just need to match with the next key

With the below code, I am not able to achieve the expected output.

```js
const processObject = ({ Next, ...rest }) => {
  const result = { ...rest };
  if (formatData.find((y) => y.Key == 'special')) {
    
    const nextObject = formatData.find((y) => y.Key == 'special')
    if (nextObject.specialkey) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nextObject.specialkey.length; i++) {
        let currentObject = formatData.find((y) => y.id === nextObject.specialkey[i].value)
        nextObject.specialkey[i].value = currentObject
      }
            
      result.Next = {
        [nextObject.Key]: processObject(nextObject),
      };
    }
  }
  if (Next) {
    const nextObject = formatData.find((y) => y.id === Next);
    result.Next = {
      [nextObject.Key]: processObject(nextObject),
    };
  }
  return result;
};
    
const response = {
  [formatData[0].Key]: processObject(formatData[0]),
};
return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```js
const input = [
  {
    "id": "p1", "top": 130, "left" :298, "Key": "test1",
    // I've changed this from "special" to "p2"
    "Next": "p2"
  // rest of input is the same...
  },{"id":"p2","Key":"special","specialkey":[{"key":"1","value":"p3"},{"key":"0","value":"p4"},{"key":"2","value":"p5"}],"Next":"","RepeatText": "p8","RepeatTextNew":"p9"},{"id":"p3","user":"aa","Key":"test3","Text":"hi"},{"id":"p4","Key":"special","specialkey":[{"key":"1","value":"p6"},{"key":"0","value":"p7"}]},{"id":"p5","user":"aa","Key":"test5","Text":"hi"},{"id":"p6","user":"aa","Key":"test6","Text":"hi"},{"id":"p7","user":"aa","Key":"test7","Text":"hi"},{"id":"p8","user":"aa","Key":"test8","Text":"hi"},{"id":"p9","user":"aa","Key":"test9","Text": "hi"}];

// Gets an object by its id
const getById = id => input.find(x => x.id === id);

const processObject = ({ Next, specialkey, RepeatText, RepeatTextNew, ...rest }) => {
  let processedNext;
  if (Next) {
    const nextObject = getById(Next);
    processedNext = { [nextObject.Key]: processObject(nextObject) };
  }
  return {
    ...rest,
    // This spread syntax means we don't add the Next or
    // specialkey property if it isn't present in the input
    // object
    ...processedNext ? { Next: processedNext } : {},
    ...RepeatText
      ? { RepeatText: { [RepeatText]: processObject(getById(RepeatText)) } }
      : {},
    ...RepeatTextNew
      ? { RepeatTextNew: { [RepeatTextNew]: processObject(getById(RepeatTextNew)) } }
      : {},
    ...specialkey
      ? {
        specialkey: specialkey.map(({ key, value }) => ({
          key,
          value: processObject(getById(value))
        }))
      }
      : {}
  };
}

console.log(processObject(input[0]));
```

In your code, you seem to be looking up objects by their `id`, so that's why I changed the first object input's `Next` from `"special"` (the `Key` of the `p2` object) to `"p2"`.

Comment: Json can also have few extra key like RepeatText and RepeatTextNew. I have updated the input and expected output.Please check

Comment: @user13000875 I’ve updated my answer. Next time, please include *all* information in your question. If someone answers your question and you come back and say ‘there's more I didn’t tell you in the first place’, that can be frustrating for the answerer and can discourage them from answering your question.